# how to refer one function for more than one google chart event listeners?

Tags: jquery, google-visualization

Hi i have three google charts in one page.i am calling only one function when ever they selected.i want to know which chart is selected?
here is my code

```
 google.visualization.events.addListener(chart1, 'select',selectHandler);
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart2, 'select',selectHandler);
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart3, 'select',selectHandler);
function selectHandler(e){
alert("title"+e.title);

}
```

i want to know which chart selected and that chart title.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The events do not pass any information about the parent chart that spawned the event, so you need to use an intermediary function to pass the chart information:

```
function selectHandler(myChart){
    // do something with myChart
}

google.visualization.events.addListener(chart1, 'select', function () {
    selectHandler(chart1);
});
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart2, 'select', function () {
    selectHandler(chart2);
});
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart3, 'select', function () {
    selectHandler(chart3);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this` or `e.currentTarget`. Both should be the same element.

So :

```
this.title;
e.currentTarget.title;
```

Comment: it is giving currentTarget as null

Comment: @user3041176 What about `this`?